# Удаление дубликатов из массива

Tags: php, массивы

Необходимо полностью удалить повторяющиеся элементы массива.
Например:

```
array("Красный", "Желтый", "Красный", "Белый");
```

Результат:

```
array("Желтый", "Белый");
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Хотел сделать элегантно, но не получилось :-/

```
$test = array("Красный", "Желтый", "Красный", "Белый");
$elCounts = array_count_values($test);
$result = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($test); ++$i) {
    foreach ($elCounts as $k => $v) {
        if ($test[$i] == $k && $v == 1) {
            $result[] = $test[$i];
            break;
        }
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

[array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-count-values.php) -  Подсчитывает количество всех значений массива
например

```
$array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
print_r(array_count_values($array));
```

Выведет:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)
```

Зная это, проходим в цикле по основному массиву и внутри по массиву, содержащий количество вхождений. Если количество вхождений равно 1, то заносим в результирующий массив

---

Другой вариант через `array_filter`.

[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php) - Фильтрует элементы массива с помощью callback-функции

```
$test = array("Красный", "Желтый", "Красный", "Белый");
$elCounts = array_count_values($test);

$result = array_filter($test, function($el) use ($elCounts) {
    foreach ($elCounts as $k => $v) {
        if ($el == $k && $v == 1) {
            return $el;
        }
    }
});

sort($result);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 14):

Если надо удалить только *дубликаты*, но оставить оригиналы (то есть получить `("Красный", "Желтый", "Белый")`, то достаточно воспользоваться предназначенной для этого функцией `array_unique()` (плюс опционально `array_values()` чтобы восстановить нумерацию).

Если же надо удалить как дубли, так и оригиналы, то можно использовать следующий код:

```
<?php

$array = array("Красный", "Желтый", "Красный", "Белый");
$result = array_diff($array, array_diff_assoc($array, array_unique($array)));
print_r($result);
```

Вывод:

```
Array (
     [1] => Желтый
     [3] => Белый
)
```

Объяснение:

С помощью [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) мы выбираем уникальные значения.
С помощью [`array_diff_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) находим расхождение, с учетом ключей.
С помощью [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php), который не учитывает ключи, убиваем эти повторения.

Пример на [Ideone](http://ideone.com/GCdTA1)

Answer (score 6):

```
function delDuplicate( $arr ) {
    $arr2 = array_count_values( $arr );
    return array_keys(array_filter( $arr2, function($x)use ($arr2) {return $arr2[$x]==1;}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY ) );
};
$test = array("Красный", "Желтый", "Красный", "Белый");
var_dump( delDuplicate( $test ) );
```

Результат:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "Желтый"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "Белый"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
function del_duplicate ($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        $arr_keys = array_keys($arr,$value);
        if(count($arr_keys)>1) {
            foreach ($arr_keys as $value_duplicate) {
                unset($arr[$value_duplicate]);
            }
        }   
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Для каждого значения массива находим ключи, если их больше 1 (значение не уникально) - удаляем все элементы с таким значением.

Comment: На всякий случай ключи сбросьте тоже в конце...Чтоб у массива ключи с нуля по возрастанию были `sort($arr);
    return $arr;`

Comment: Алексей, спасибо за рекомендацию! Но мне кажется если будет необходимость перестроить ключи, это можно будет сделать позднее (и только тем кому это действительно нужно)

Answer (score 3):

Для тех, кто любит функциональный подход:

```
function make_it_clean($arr) {
    return array_values(array_map(
        function($item) {
            return $item['val'];
        },
        array_filter(
            array_reduce(
                $arr,
                function($carry, $item) {
                    if (!array_key_exists($item, $carry)) {
                        $carry[$item] = [
                            'val' => $item,
                            'count' => 0,
                        ];
                    }
                    $carry[$item]['count']++;

                    return $carry;
                },
                []
            ),
            function($item) {
                return $item['count'] === 1;
            }
        )
    ));
}

var_dump(make_it_clean(["Красный", "Желтый", "Красный", "Белый"]));
```

Ну и по традиции рабочий [пример](http://ideone.com/WBOtdK) на IDEOne.

**UPD:**

Весь жуткий кусок кода выше всего лишь сводится к `reduce->filter->map` последовательности. Но из-за магии PHP вместо красивой и чистой функиональщины получается монструозный комок грязи.

Answer (score 3):

```
$array = array_unique($array);
```

Comment: Смешно, единственный правильный ответ в самом низу

Answer (score -1):

Как-то так. Работает с числами, с буквами.

```
/*
Сделайте функцию, 
которая параметром будет принимать массив и удалять из него все дубликаты. 
*/

$arr = ['andrey','andrey',3,'igor',5,5,4,3,'igor',1,1000,'igor','misha']; /*Дан массив с некоторыми значениями*/ 
$key = 0; /*Ключ элемента в массиве. В массиве счёт элементов начинается с нуля */

$copy_arr = $arr; /* Делаем копию массива $arr. 
Будем сравнивать элементы массива $arr с элементами дубликата $copy_arr.*/

$final_arr = []; /*Создаем пустой массив, куда будем помещать 
элементы массива $arr без повторяющихся значений*/

while ($key < count($arr)){ /*Начинаем цикл: пока ключ массива меньше длины массива */
    array_shift($copy_arr); /* Удаляем первый элемент в массиве $copy_arr, чтобы
    сравнивать первый элемент с последующими. Например: Первый элемент - это 1, 
    мы будем 1 сравнивать с 2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1,1000. */
    $copy_key = 0; /* Ключ массива $copy_arr */
    $buff = 0; /*Наш счётчик */
    while ($copy_key < count($copy_arr)){ /*Начинаем второй цикл при этом первый цикл ещё не завершился.
        Тут мы выполняем действия, пока ключ массива $copy_arr меньше длины массива $copy_arr*/
        if ($arr[$key] == $copy_arr[$copy_key]){/*
                   Если элемент массива $arr совпадает с элементом массива $copy_arr,
                   то счётчик увеличивает на единицу.
                   Не забываем, что массив $copy_arr,
                   мы продолжаем сокращать на один элемент с начала */
            $buff++;
        }
        $copy_key++; /* Ключ массива $copy_arr увеличиваем на единицу, чтоб перебрать все его элементы*/
    }
    if ($buff == 0){ /*Если наш счётчик не нашел одинаковых элементов,
                       то добавляем этот элемент в финальный массив $final_arr */
        array_push($final_arr, $arr[$key]); /*То самое добавление в финальный массив */
    }
    $key++; /*Ключ массива $arr увеличиваем на единицу, чтоб перебрать все его элементы*/
}
print_r($final_arr); /* Выводим наш финальный массив с элементами без повторов */
```

Comment: Я извиняюсь, а чем array_unique-то не угодил?