# Вывод только уникальных элементов массива в единственном числе

Tags: php, массивы

Никак не соображу, что добавить в этот код, чтобы он сработал на вывод только уникальных значений (т.е. 3, 0)

```
<?php

$arr = array(2, 5, 5, 3, 2, 10, 10, 0);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++ ) {
   $a = true;
   for($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++){
      if($arr[$i] == $arr[$j]){
         $a = false;
      }
   }
   if($a){
      echo $arr[$i]. " ";
   }
}

?>
```

А сейчас выводятся все элементы в единственном числе(т.е. 2, 5, 3, 10, 0)

Comment: опять без использования встроенных функций? :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, точно xD

Comment: конечно, Алексей)). Но было бы круто если бы и со встроенными и без показали)

Comment: ну с использованием функций вам сюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/527844/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0/527851#527851  .......... без функций чуть по-другому

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вариант без встроенных функций:

```
<?php

$arr = array(2, 5, 5, 3, 2, 10, 10, 0);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++ ) {
   $a = true;
   $n = 0;
   for($j = 0; $j < count($arr); $j++){
      if($arr[$i] == $arr[$j]){
         $n = $n + 1;
         if($n > 1){
            $a = false;
         }
      }
   }
   if($a){
      echo $arr[$i]. " ";
   }
}

?>
```

Comment: а...вот оно как...круто..просто добавить переменную  и с ней сделать условие...я понял. Спасибо!

Comment: эх... решение за квадрат, я надеялся за n log n хотя бы)

Comment: @pavel, непонял )

Comment: @Yuri ну тут сложность решения O(n^2) я думал O(n log n) будет ответ или даже O(n).

Comment: @pavel, мда.. :)

Comment: @pavel а у вас есть такое решение?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский на псевдокоде есть, на С++ есть, на php нету.

Comment: @pavel неважно, просто интересно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский O(n) - использовать hash_map/set или что там есть из такого. O(n log n) - сортировка + чуть-чуть исправленный метод unique.

Comment: @pavel разве hashset не тупо удалит дубликаты и оставит по одному значению от каждого?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский чуть-чуть не так, в 2 прохода, 1 - подсчёт, 2 - фильтр по значению в мапе. А так как нам пофиг на точное количество, то можно вместо мапы обойтись сетом аккуратно.